# Importing data into a 2D array from MSSQL database

Tags: python, arrays, sql-server, django

I am trying to print a trial balance through a web app.

The app currently prints the description but not in a line by line format, I have had a look at the .filter function but I don't know how that would translate to MSSQL queries.

If anyone one has any examples for me , that would be a great help.

Views.py :

```
def home(request):
    desc = "SELECT Description FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[_btblCbStatement] WHERE Account <> ''"
    cursor = cnxn.cursor();
    cursor.execute(desc);
    description = cursor.fetchall()
    return render(request , 'main/home.html' , {"description": description})
```

Home.html:

```
{% extends "main/base.html"%}

{% block content%}
<h1>HOME</h1>
{% for description in description %}
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col">
    <p>{{ description }}</p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}   
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchall` returns a list of tuples (in this case a list of one-tuples since there is a single column in the SELECT clause).

The easiest way to fix this will be to convert `description` to a list of strings beforehand:

```
description = [tup[0] for tup in cursor.fetchall()]
```

BTW, I think `{% endfor %}` is on the wrong line. It should go **after** the closing `</div>` tag.